# Are there 5/5 Beast Token cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are at least two cards that I know of that make 5/5 Beast tokens ([Spawning Ground](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spawning%20Ground) and [One Dozen Eyes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=One%20Dozen%20Eyes)).

Yet I can't seem to find an actual token card that is a 5/5 Beast.

Does such a card exist? I know I could use a die that has a 5 on it, or take a 3/3 and write 5s over them.  But this question is for someone who is into the real token cards.

If they do exist, how would I find some?

Comment: I'm glad to know I wasn't the only one wondering about this!  I was looking for a 5/5 beast token for my cube, and while I suspected there wasn't one I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a pretty comprehensive list of official MTG tokens and similar cards](http://magiccards.info/extras.html). I can't find a 5/5 Beast on that list.

As a rule of thumb:

- Putting tokens in packs only really started around Tenth Edition, and has been done consistently since. The cards from before that are special promos.
- In the modern day, sets sold in booster packs have tokens and emblems as some of the inserts (typically mixed with ad and rules tip cards). Pre-built sets like Commander products and Duel Decks may or may not come with token cards.
- Wizards of the Coast does not make "copy" tokens (how would you?), but they do print specific tokens with abilities listed on the cards, as well as tokens with variable P/T.

In this case, [the cards that produce 5/5 Beasts](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20%5B5/5%5D%20%5BBeast%5D) are from Mirrodin and Commander 2013. [Mirrodin came before Tenth Edition](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=mtg/tcg/products/allproducts), while Commander 2013 is a non-randomized set that didn't include tokens.

Comment: I would rather say that it's only with (roughly) Tenth Edition that Wizards started making tokens for _all_ cards that produced token creatures; while the ones before that were promos, there really were _quite_ a few of them (as they were used for player rewards promos).  For instance, I have several of the 4/4 beast token from Odyssey.  Mirrodin more falls in the 'dead zone' in between the two different styles of token production.